# How to simulate a production cluster to test the hadoop jobs in single machine

Tags: hadoop

I want to run hadoop jobs on development workstation for testing before submitting into production. Which mode operation in hadoop allows to most closely simulate a production cluster while using a single machine.

Answer (score 0):

I use pseudo-distributed mode on my vmware image to test before deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudera's CDH4 in pseudo-distributed mode runs on a single machine. The simulation of multiple workers is done via command line, very easy! And the documentation---if followed accurately---is everything you will need to read to get your cluster to run.

I have not made any performance tests to compare it to Chris Gerken's suggestion: the VMware simulation but I wouldn't be surprised to see it run more efficiently. Anyway, as you just want to test it on a Linux machine, either will be fine, I guess.